# How to create an "Application Signed Request" with Sinch using PHP

Tags: php, rest, sinch

I am trying to use the Sinch Rest API with PHP to mute and unmute specific participants from Conference calls but have not been able to find an example of how to send an application signed request with PHP. I have been trying to work off of this documentation from Sinch here https://www.sinch.com/docs/voice/rest/index.html#muteunmuteconfparticipant

My initial guesses are that this would require the use of CURL and that I would also need to use similar pieces of this example to sign my application but I"m not sure how to combine the two. https://github.com/sinch/php-auth-ticket

Any help appreciated. Thanks!

edit: @cjensen I added this code snippet I've been working on to try and use as the signed request maker. It's very similar to that github link above

```
<?php

    class SinchTicketGenerator
    {
        private $applicationKey; 
        private $applicationSecret;
        public function __construct($applicationKey, $applicationSecret)
        {
            $this->applicationKey = $applicationKey;
            $this->applicationSecret = $applicationSecret;
        }
        public function generateTicket()
        {
            $request = [
                'command' => 'mute',
            ];
            $requestJson = preg_replace('/\s+/', '', json_encode($request));
            $requestBase64 = $this->base64Encode($requestJson);
            $digest = $this->createDigest($requestJson);
            $signature = $this->base64Encode($digest);
            $requestSigned = $requestBase64.':'.$signature;
            return $requestSigned;
        }
        private function base64Encode($data)
        {
            return trim(base64_encode($data));
        }
        private function createDigest($data)
        {
            return trim(hash_hmac('sha256', $data, base64_decode($this->applicationSecret), true));
        }
    }

    $generator = new SinchTicketGenerator('app-key', 'app-secret');
    $signedrequest = $generator->generateTicket();
    echo $signedrequest;

?>
```

Comment: Show what code you have now, please

Comment: thanks, @cjensen. I've added code example